# Hard disk partition missing in MY COMPUTER

Tags: windows-7

My E and F drive, which is a partition on my main hard drive used for storing data, has disappeared. I am using Windows 7 and the partition was almost full with data.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on my computer, select Manage. From there, click on Disk Management and see if you see your disk and partitions.

Click on the blue-headed title according to your drive and select change drive letter and paths, click on add and choose add a new drive letter.

Comment: Not working it says " The operation failed to complete because the disk management console view is not up to date

Answer (score 0):

Go to disk management and select change drive letters and paths,add new drive letter.

otherwise go to `Organize -> Folder and Search Options-> click on the View tab`. Uncheck the box called "**Hide empty drives in the Computer folder**".